# Why Django Commands are working well outside the virtual environment and doesn't work inside virtual environment

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I recently installed Django on my machine, I installed virtualenv, virtualenv-wrapper and i even customized the ~/.bashrc file but;
Some commands like "python3 manage.py startapp" give me an error when inside the virtual environment but do work outside the virtual environment, I wanna know why?
why is it that django commands dont run in zsh shell but do run in bash shell?
Note:: Am writing all the commands in the folder containing manage.py and the django local server is already running

[My working terminal1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCoV5.png)

[My working terminal2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH4tw.png)

Comment: Looks like you haven't installed the packages you require in your virtual environment, at a minimum you need to install django - run this when your venv is active `python3 -m pip install django` and then run your command again to confirm

Comment: okay let me try out